# Open Activity from App-Widget, opens the last Activity

Tags: android

I have a function to open an Activity from the App-Widget like this:

```
 protected PendingIntent openSettingsPedingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);
    settingsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, settingsIntent, 0);
}
```

This works fine, but the App-Widget open the last Activity from my App, not the `SettingsActivity`, when I do the following steps:

1. Kill the app via task manager
2. Reopen the App via App-Widget
3. Switch from SettingsActivity to another Activity
4. Press the home button

When I now click on the App-Widget its open the last Activity I had open in my App, not the `SettingsActivity`. 
Any ideas why this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace `0` in `PendingIntent` with `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);
settingsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```